# Highcharts - How to show more than 30 columns side by side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts 6.1.1 with react-highcharts 16.0.0.  When I create a 'column' style chart with 30 series or less, the data points with matching x-values all are arranged side by side:[image: chart working as i want with fewer than 31 series]

But, if i add another series, bringing the total to 31, Highcharts no longer groups the columns side by side, and instead renders them all in the same place, not stacked, just overlapping:[image: over 30 series doesn't group]
I can't seem to find a setting in highcharts config to change this grouping threshold, and have experimented quite a bit with setting paddings and widths and such to try to maximize the number of columns it will show side by side, but i can never get it to work with more than 30 series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the boost part of the config:

```js
config = {
  boost: {
      enabled: true,
      useGPUTranslations: true,
      seriesThreshold: 30
   },
 }
```

So I can up that seriesThreshold or just disable boost for this case to solve the problem. Though I would like to know if there's a way to get the boost rendering to correctly show the columns side by side.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the boost module, columns are always one pixel wide. Additionally, a lot of functionality (such as **grouping**, which causes this problem) is disabled when the boost module works.

Here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6600, you have very well explained the assumptions of this module.

To work around, you can use decimal `x` values:

```
series: [{
    data: [1]
}, {
    data: [2, 2]
}, {
    data: [{
        x: 0.3,
        y: 1
    }]
}, {
    data: [2]
}, ... ]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8bq9yL4f/